# including executable file with gem

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, gemspecs

The gem in question is on my [GItHub](https://github.com/adam-wanninger/fails)

I am also on Linux, specifically Ubuntu. I am trying to make the gem compatible for Linux/OSX users at this point, with a focus on Windows users after it is working correctly for *nix systems.

So I have written a gem called `fails`. It can be used to build a test automation suite with the Ruby/Cucumber/Watir-webdriver stack around web applications written in other languages, and with other frameworks.

It creates powerful command line generation tools for building page objects and feature files using several commands, which are:

```
fails g page <page object name>
fails f <feature file name>
fails n <new automated test suite name>
```

I have written an appropriate executable file that should, on installing the gem, allow a user to call `fails <arg> <arg> <arg>...etc` from command line. However, when building the gem and installing it, I try and generate a page object by calling `fails g page google` but I get the error:

```
daniel@d:~/Downloads/fails_gem$ fails
/usr/local/bin/fails:23:in `load': /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/fails-0.0.3/bin/fails:4: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
fails.rb ARGV[0] ARGV[1] ARGV[2] ARGV[3] ARGV[4] A...
                     ^
    from /usr/local/bin/fails:23:in `<main>'
```

This error is telling me that something is wrong with my executable file, but I don't quite understand what. I need to be able to call `fails.rb` with up to nine command line arguments. My executable file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'fails'
fails.rb ARGV[0] ARGV[1] ARGV[2] ARGV[3] ARGV[4] ARGV[5] ARGV[6] ARGV[7] ARGV[8] ARGV[9]
```

The gem is really new and unpolished, so any open source support would be great if there is interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about the contents of the executable `bin/fails`. This should be plain Ruby. It looks like you are trying to use some sort of combination Ruby and shell syntax with the line `fails.rb ARGV[0] ...`, which isn’t going to work.

In this case all I think you need is the `require 'fails'` line. This should load the file `lib/fails.rb` (since Rubygems will have added `lib` to your load path), and then the contents or `ARGV` will still be available in that file.

Comment: OK awesome. I was thrown off by the tutorial on rubygems.org that teaches you how to create the `hola` gem. I reduced the executable file to just a shebang and `require 'fails'` and it's working great. Out of curiosity, do I have to do anything special to the executable to get the same functionality on Windows?

Comment: @FluffyKittens I don’t think so (I don’t have a Windows machine to test). I saw your `fails.bat` file – Rubygems creates a wrapper file for executables that sets up the load path etc. On Windows I think it creates an appropriate `.bat` file for you, so you shouldn’t need anything like that.

Comment: Thanks. I had previously created that .bat file manually with the intent of creating an executable file to move it into bin. Guess that's not important anyone.